# Mark of the Web is not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, mark-of-the-web

I'm getting the warning message `internet explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or activex controls` while opening our application in IE 9. I have tried adding [Mark Of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx) as described in some online resources. Even if it is not showing the message when we open the page, it's popping up when we refresh the page.

This is the starting of my html file.

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html lang="en">`

How can we avoid this message without changing the settings manually ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems IE is very temperamental: if you use a line ending other than `CRLF` then it silently ignores the Mark of the Web (it's as if they're *trying* to wind up developers).